# ISCLONE() and Workflow Rules against CLONED records

Tags: apex, formula, inputcheckboxes, checkmarx

I am trying to create some business logic that resets a cloned Opportunity check-box field to FALSE if that Opportunity record is cloned (our sales team will clone opportunities with the same accounts for new upsell opps.

Here is what I have tried

```
IF (ISCLONE(),
Example_Checkbox_field1__c = FALSE,
Example_Checkbox_field1__c = TRUE)
```

However, using ISCLONE in any IF() statements returns this syntax error:

> Function ISCLONE may not be used in this type of formula

Edit: Even though Google and Salesforce Documentation did not help, I figured out that this rule is only acceptable if the Eval Criteria is set to "Created, and every time it's edited.'

Edit NOTE: This rule will not work if Eval Criteria is "Created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria," OR (more importantly) the first choice of "Created"

Is there a way to create a formula that sets the 'Example_Checkbox_field1__c' field to FALSE right after 'Clone' button was clicked and BEFORE the record is saved?

Comment: You could create a custom clone button that would mark the record appropriately. Unfortunately if they cancel the clone will still be marked. There are a lot of prices items you need to figure out first (what if they cancel, what if the clone is deleted, etc).

Comment: @Eric interesting idea. What am I really trying to do is change a Field value BEFORE it is saved as a new record. 
So process would be 'Sales rep'->clicks 'CLONE'-> Example_Checkbox__c reset back FALSE in the actual Edit page

Comment: Sounds like you might want to implement a BeforeInsert trigger to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: You could create a custom button to clone that does a URL hack to set the checkbox field to false: /{!Opportunity.Id}/e?clone=1&00No000000CVfXG=0&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id} The 00No000000CVfXG would be replaced with the html element id that Salesforce has given the checkbox on your page layout. Or, you could use an app like SuperClone on the AppExchange to set values in a cloned record.